# Using boolean operators with ternary operators in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

**NB**: Someone please explain how to format my code here, it just doesn't work, Im doing it wrong or something.


Here is my code after refactoring according to comments, **it now works!**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const App = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('effect');
        axios
            .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
            .then(response => {
                console.log('promise fulfilled');
                const countries = response.data
                setCountries(countries)
            })
    }, [])
    const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('')
    const searchOnChangeEventHandler = (event) => setSearchVal(event.target.value)
    const filteredCountries = (searchVal, countries) => countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase()))
    const filteredCountriesLength = filteredCountries(searchVal, countries).length
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>coutries data</h1>
            <div>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='search countries'
                    value={searchVal}
                    onChange={searchOnChangeEventHandler}
                >
                </input>
            </div>

            <div>
                <>
                    {
                        countries.length
                            ? (searchVal
                                ? (
                                    filteredCountriesLength <= 10 && filteredCountriesLength > 1
                                        ? filteredCountries(searchVal, countries).map(country => <p key={country.name}>{country.name}</p>)
                                        : <span>{filteredCountriesLength} matches! too many matches, specify another filter...</span>
                                )
                                : <span>type to search..</span>)
                            : <span>populating countries data...</span>
                    }
                </>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}
export default App
```

The following piece now works the way I wanted it to, after I cleaned up the code, I think its better to use if-else and then convert to ternary as suggested.

```js
        <div>
            <>
                {
                    countries.length
                        ? (searchVal
                            ? (
                                filteredCountriesLength <= 10 && filteredCountriesLength > 1
                                    ? filteredCountries(searchVal, countries).map(country => <p key={country.name}>{country.name}</p>)
                                    : <span>{filteredCountriesLength} matches! too many matches, specify another filter...</span>
                            )
                            : <span>type to search..</span>)
                        : <span>populating countries data...</span>
                }
            </>
        </div>
```

**NB**: Is there a way to strip all this white-space in the code?

I wanted to print `type to search whenever the searchVal input was empty`.

Comment: So what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Even if you get it working somehow, the result will be hardly maintainable. Consider moving this part to a separate function or a component.

Comment: Usually I just do many if statements in normal if(){} and then I change it to ternary

Comment: the code isnt formatting correctly i cant get it to format

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure about what you're asking for but I think it would help you by moving the ternaries into a function like:

```
const handleRender = () => {
  const length = filteredCountries(searchVal, countries)?.length

  if (length) {
    if (length <= 10) {
      return filteredCountries(searchVal, countries).map(country => <p key={country.name}>{country.name}</p>)
    } else {
      return <span>please be more specific, add filter...</span>
    }
  } 

  return <span>populating countries data...</span>
}

// render
{handleRender()}
```

Comment: In the future, just edit your previously deleted answer and undelete it.

Comment: how would i add an if else to print 'type to search' when searchVal is an `''`

Comment: @utsavojha95 it depends on what takes precedence, if you want to show "type to search" no matter what, even if you have filteredCountries, i would add a check above `if (length)` and check `if(searchVal === '') return <span>Type to search</span>`